# Как создать хранимую процедуру, которая принимает в себя аргументы?

Tags: sql, хранимые-процедуры

Хочу создать хранимую процедуру, в которую программист будет передавать аргумены.
Пусть есть таблица `animal` с полями  `anim_id(int)`, `anim_name (varchar)`.

Я хочу создать инсертный метод, который примет число и имя и добавит в таблицу зверя:

```
create Procedure addAnimal(int id, varchar name){ //Псевдокод 
insert into animal values(id,name); 
}
```

**Вопросы:**
Как создать такую процедуру?

Какой командой вызвать? (подойдёт ли, к примеру, `call addAnimal(12, 'dog');` ?)

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: MySQL 8. Но если знаете ответ, дайте также для PostgreSQL, для Oracle и прочих БД. Потому что не гуглится (или я гуглить не умею).

Comment: **"Какой командой вызвать?"** Из ?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky не ясен синтаксис вызова метода (c параметрами) из самой MySQL.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html https://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx Ваш вопрос не подходит для stackoverflow.com

Comment: почему не подходит?

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Здесь суть вопроса другая. Я писал

Comment: функцию. У меня не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ca76832e6f65857ade59dacd0d5b358)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl (
     anim_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
     anim_name varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO tbl(anim_name) 
VALUES 
('cat'),
('donkey');

SELECT * FROM tbl;

CREATE PROCEDURE addAnimal(IN name VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl (anim_name) 
    VALUES (name);
END

CALL addAnimal('cow');

SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Всё примерно как мне нужно. Скажите пожалуйста, а если id не объявлять primary key, можно ли в MYSQL запихнуть два аргумента в процедуру?

Comment: Мне кажется, нужен DELIMITER $$ перед `create procedure`

Comment: У процедуры может быть два или более параметров. Не забудьте проверить ссылку SQL Fiddle. Чтобы увидеть, как это работает. **"...DELIMITER $$ перед create procedure..."** - незачем.